# there is no certificate installed on this server

Tags: ssl, remote-desktop

I want to secure a remote desktop connection using ssl.  I provided a CA server, created a self-signed certificate, and then I installed that in remote server.  When I tried to assign a certificate to the rdp service I received this error `"there is no certificate installed on this server"`.  Import that in computer account in certificate console and user account, but the error is continuing.

I wonder if some one can help me.

Comment: What certificate store are you importing the certificate into?

Comment: computer account/trusted root certification authority

Answer (score 1):

You need to install he certificated used for RDP on the server into the computer's Personal store.